# telerik radgridview winforms order programmatically added columns

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I set up a RadGridView and setup 2 Columns at Design Time and then added some GridViewComboBoxColumns programmatically.
Now I want to reorder the columns, so that the first 2 columns are at the end.

I tried:

```
private void Grid_Standort_DataBindingComplete(object sender, GridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            Grid_Standort.Columns.Move(0, 5);
            Grid_Standort.Columns.Move(1, 6);
            Grid_Standort.Columns.Move(2, 0);
            Grid_Standort.Columns.Move(3, 1);
            Grid_Standort.Columns.Move(4, 2);
            Grid_Standort.Columns.Move(5, 3);
            Grid_Standort.Columns.Move(6, 4);
        }
```

But that doesn't change anything.

Comment: This code works just fine on my end. Make sure to post a whole sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead in the **DataBindingComplete**, execute this code on a simple button click and see if it works.
2. If it works, you can see if the **DataBindingComplete** event is fired at all.
3. If it is, then you need to move the code in a later event e.g. **Form.Shown**

Lastly, you can try the **Insert** method of the *Columns* collection:

```
radGridView1.Columns.Insert(index, column);
```

Comment: Thank you, the programmatically added columns weren't available at DataBindingComplete, so moving the reordering to Form.Shown has worked.